# Release output slower than Debug: MD5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash()

Tags: c#, optimization, md5

I'm calculating the MD5 hash of files periodically by the code below. The files are about 10MB.
When I run my program in Debug mode (Debug | x64) the call to ComputeHash() takes 35ms and if built in Release mode (Release | x64) it takes 400ms - both tested without debugger attached, for the same file and re-tested mutile times.

(I tried with visual studio express 2010 and 2012 - same result).

What can I do to get the good Debug-Preformance in Release mode? Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

The code:

```
public static string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  if (File.Exists(fileName))
  {
    var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

    //for benchmarking
    var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

    //for benchmarking
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

    stream.Close();

    for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
      sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i tested on visual studio 2008, to me debug & release mode have almost same performance!

Comment: Don't use `Stopwatch` - try using a `DateTime` object and subtract for time difference. Above that - I have no idea

Comment: @AppDeveloper What file did you use? A "random" 10 megabyte file?

Comment: @QuanticProgramming Why do you think `DateTime.Now` will produce precise results for durations much less than one second?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Files are html log files with many lines like "<div> ... </div>". Tried with DateTime: same result.

Comment: Can you try to read all the file into memory with `File.ReadAllBytes()` method _before_ you start the `Stopwatch`? So no `Stream`. Then call `ComputeHash` on the byte array. It would be interesting to see if this was related to I/O or not. (I'm not suggesting that there's anything wrong with your code, I just thought it would be interesting to measure this way also.)

Comment: OK, changed the code to first calculate the file bytes (byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);) and then measure the md5 calculation (byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(fileBytes);). Result: Debug 3ms, Release 366ms -> showing the same effect.

Comment: Strange. I really can't reproduce. I don't have your exact file, of course, but I tried with some made-up byte arrays of length `10485760`, and I get the same result with Debug and Release, both x64. However, when I change to x86, it seems to be approximately 15% faster(?). I also used .NET 4.5 (VS 2012). Maybe it depends on hardware architecture?

Comment: If you put the entire test into a loop and call it several times, do you get the same timings?

Comment: The application periodically calls the GetMD5HashFromFile() to check if the file content has changes. This way automatically the "loop-check" was performed. For the simplest test of a constant file I always get the same result (+/- some ms).

Comment: OK, in the meantime I changed the structure of the application and now the md5 calculation is performed in c++. It's works pretty fast in debug and release (by using CryptCreateHash(), CryptHashData() and CryptGetHashParam()).

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the release and the debug version via Visual Studio? If so, try running them directly outside of Visual Studio. Running them via Visual Studio will always attach the debugger to your process, causing a slow down.

Comment: When making performance checks I always use an optimized version and run the program standalone (without debugger attached).